# In Laravel 5.4 request validation only works on the first page of pagination

Tags: php, laravel

So what's happening is i'm getting an array of id's for the users posts and the users friends posts and then checking that the current page's post id is in the array of ids. This works as i wanted it to for the first page but because i'm using pagination it doesn't work for the pages after the first.

```
public function authorize(Request $request)
{
    $postRepo = $this->postRepo;
    $posts = $postRepo->index();
    $posts->all();
    $post_id = $request->route('post_id');
    $posts = $posts->pluck('id')->toArray();
    if (in_array($post_id, $posts)) {
       return true;
    }
}
```

At the moment the array of id's is only displaying those of the first page which seems to be the problem

```
array:4 [▼
0 => 10
1 => 11
2 => 9
3 => 17
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can to change your authorize() method to:

```
public function authorize(Request $request)
{
    $postRepo = $this->postRepo;
    $post_id = $request->route('post_id');

    // Here I believe that index() method return a Eloquent Builder
    $posts = $postRepo->index();

    return (boolean) $posts->where('id', $post_id)->count();
}
```

It will return true if exists $post_id in `$postRepo->index()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This still works the same way because in $posts it always has the same collection from the first page for the other pages. So when you're on say page 3 it'll still have the collection of id's from page 1.

Comment: Can you put the PostRepository class to me understand more?

Comment: I've sorted it now. Its because i was paginating the posts in the repository instead of in the controller so the posts i was using here were already being paginated so it was expecting pagination in the single post view when it shouldn't have been. Thanks for your help anyway:)